# perl command prompt with arguments

Tags: perl

Is it possible to start a command prompt from perl script using Win32::Process::Create package?
I am trying to start DOORS from perl script. The executable is present in C:\Program Files\DOORS\bin\runDOORS9.rck.
I need to start the runDOORS9.rck with the argument COL9 to change the Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the good old `system()` function. On Windows it would use the `cmd.exe`, the system shell, to execute the command.

Since what you try to launch doesn't seem to be an `.exe` file, potentially you would have to use the `start` command of the `cmd.exe`.

For example:

```
system(qq{start "" "C:\Program Files\DOORS\bin\runDOORS9.rck" COL9});
```

(The first `""` is required due to quirky argument parsing of the Window's shell commands. See `help start` for more information.)